# Numpy advanced indexing fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-indexing

I have a numpy array looking like this:

```
 a = np.array([[0.87, 1.10, 2.01, 0.81 , 0.64,        0.        ],
   [0.87, 1.10, 2.01, 0.81 , 0.64,        0.        ],
   [0.87, 1.10, 2.01, 0.81 , 0.64,        0.        ],
   [0.87, 1.10, 2.01, 0.81 , 0.64,        0.        ],
   [0.87, 1.10, 2.01, 0.81 , 0.64,        0.        ],
   [0.87, 1.10, 2.01, 0.81 , 0.64,        0.        ]])
```

I like to manipulate this by setting the 'bottom left' part to zero. Instead of looping through rows and columns, I want to achieve this by means of indexing:

```
ix = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

However `a[ix]` does not deliver what I expect, as `a[ix].shape` is now `(6,6,6)`, i.e. a new dimension has been added. What do I need to do in order to preserve the shape of `a`, but with all zeros in the bottom left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to have to worry about creating `ix` at all, what you're really asking for is the upper triangle of `a`, which is the method [`numpy.triu`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.triu.html)

```
np.triu(a)
```

```
array([[0.87, 1.1 , 2.01, 0.81, 0.64, 0.  ],
       [0.  , 1.1 , 2.01, 0.81, 0.64, 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 2.01, 0.81, 0.64, 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.81, 0.64, 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.64, 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need advanced indexing for this purpose. [Boolean indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) would be more suitable with what you have:

```
a[~ix.astype(bool)] = 0
a
#array([[ 0.87,  1.1 ,  2.01,  0.81,  0.64,  0.  ],
#       [ 0.  ,  1.1 ,  2.01,  0.81,  0.64,  0.  ],
#       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  2.01,  0.81,  0.64,  0.  ],
#       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.81,  0.64,  0.  ],
#       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.64,  0.  ],
#       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ]])
```